# Finding lowest possible value

Tags: optimization, arithmetic, means

please help me with this problem:

Find the lowest possible value of 
$$
x+y^3
$$
where both x and y are positive and x*y=1.

I know how to solve this one using my method, but I was suggested to use **geometric and arithmetic mean**. I have no idea how to solve this using them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $xy = 1$, observe that $x + y^3 = y^{-1} + y^3 = y^3 + \frac{y^{-1}}{3} + \frac{y^{-1}}{3} + \frac{y^{-1}}{3} \geq 4\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{3^3}}$.

The equality holds if and only if $y^3 = \frac{y^{-1}}{3}$, that means for $y = \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{3}} > 0$, therefore your lowest possible value of $x + y^3$ is $4\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{3^3}}$.

Comment: Nice. But not obvious!

Comment: The intuition is to somehow get rid of "3" in the $y^3$ through the AM-GM inequality and $xy = 1$ implies taking $x = y^{-1}$ which quickly suggests such representation of $x + y^3$.

Comment: That's helpful. In so doing we get a concrete number for the lower bound. Add that to the tool kit.

Comment: @tosi3k great solution, thank you very much :). 
Could you please explain more precisely why "The equality holds if and only if 
$$
y^3=\frac{y^{-1}}{3}
$$
?

Comment: If you have positive reals $a_1, ..., a_n$, the inequality between arithmetic and geometric mean looks as follows: $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j \geq \left(\prod_{j=1}^{n}a_j\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
and the inequality becomes an equality if and only if $a_1 = a_2 = ... = a_n$

Comment: @tosi3k ok, I understand. And now when we achieved AM=GM, why do we consider this as the lowest value?

Comment: We have a lower bound on the minimal value of $x + y^3$ equal to a constant $4\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{3^3}}$, right? And now we want to proof that this bound is in fact our minimal value. I meant that in our AM-GM inequality application we can attain equality to this lower bound by seeking such $y$ that $y^3 = \frac{y^{-1}}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is to find the minimum value of $$f(x; y) = x + y^3$$ but moving only along the curve $$x*y = 1$$ in the Oxy plane, like in the picture:

[Plot for f(x; y) = x + y^3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMvjX.png)

To solve this, use the condition $$x*y = 1$$, to substitute y and express the function only in terms of x:

$$y = 1/x$$

$$f(x) = x + 1/x^3$$

Then find the minimum of the function f(x) and the corresponding x.
You can do it either analyticalally or numerically:

Find the first derivative $$f'(x) = 1 - 3/x^4$$

Solve it for $$f'(x) = 0$$. The root is $$x = 3^(1/4) = 1.316$$

$$y = 1/x = 0.7599$$

Finally lowest value of $$f(x; y) = 1.316 + 0.7599^3 = 1.7548$$

To solve it numerically, you can use for example the calcpad online calculator:

http://calcpad.net/Calculator

You have to type the following code:

```
f(x) = x + 1/x^3
$Plot{f(x) @ x = 0.5 : 5}
$Inf{f(x) @ x = 1: 2}
x_inf','y_inf = 1/x_inf
```

Almost all numerical methods can find a local minimum in a certain interval. That is why, it is good to plot the function first to see approximately where to search. Press "Print preview" and you will get the answer on the screen like:

[Plot of f(x) = x + 1/x^3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHBy9.png)